# Codeforces : Correct submmision giving a runtime error

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to solve this [question](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/69/A) with the following code.

```
# --- Algorithm --- #

def function(p):
    n = int(p[0])

    for i in range(n):
        tot = 0

        for num_list in p[1:len(p)]:
            num_list = num_list.split()
            number = int(num_list[i])
            tot += number

        if tot != 0:
            return "NO"

    return "YES"

# --- Run --- #

p = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        p.append(line)
    else:
        break
    
ans = function(p)
print(ans)
```

However I keep getting "Runtime error on test 1". I self-tested the input myself and it was right.

The full codeforces submission data is [here](https://codeforces.com/problemset/submission/69/131218735).